# Firefox with Vimperator: how to toggle Find bar?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

I'm using Firefox with [Vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator) Vim emulator plugin, but instead of using its `/` key for searching, I prefer to use regular built-it Find bar, invoked by `Ctrl-F`.

The problem is, if Vimperator is enabled, when I hit `Esc` from within Find bar after I'm done searching, Find bar doesn't disappear (as it would, had Vimperator been disabled) because Vimperator intercepts `Esc` mapping.

So my question is, how can I make Find bar disappear as it normally would, when I hit `Esc` key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following mapping to your `~/.vimperatorrc` Vimperator configuration file:

`inoremap <Esc> <S-Esc><Esc><S-Esc>`

And be sure to restart Firefox to pick up the changes.

Under the covers, it does the following: disables Vimperator key interception, propagates `Esc` key to Firefox (which closes Find bar), enables Vimperator key interception back, in that order. Note that this mapping is not specific to Find bar only, it applies to all `insert mode` forms (any text area where you can type in some input), but that's likely what you want anyway.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work on sites like quora.com =|

Answer (score 5):

With vimperator enabled, typing `i+CTRL+f` will bring up the find bar. And it's also easy to close it.

**Try this command:**

`:js document.getElementById("FindToolbar").close();`

**Or create a map: (Add the bellow lines to '~/.vimperatorrc')**

`noremap <c-s-f> :js document.getElementById("FindToolbar").close();<cr>`

`inoremap <c-s-f> <esc>:js document.getElementById("FindToolbar").close();<cr>`

Thus typing `CTRF+SHIFT+f` works like charm!

**An extra note:**

`CTRL+f` in command mode will bring up the find bar. Whilst `CTRL-b` will bring up bookmark sidebar. That's the reason I encounter this problem. So some other mappings might be helpful:

`cnoremap <c-f> <right>`

`cnoremap <c-b> <left>`

**Updates**:
Starting from Gecko 1.9(Firefox 25), use this command instead:
`:js getBrowser().getFindBar().close()`